# Cloudflare ignores environment variables from heroku

Tags: heroku, next.js, environment-variables, cloudflare

I have a next.js project that I connected with Heroku and I wanted to combine the Heroku project with the Cloudflare domain. The problem is that in the Cloudflare domain, every environment variable I created in Heroku was ignored and replaced with undefined values.

Comment: Why would you expect Cloudflare to be able to access your Heroku environment variables?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.